# How to get all the folders of the project regardless of its location (different machines)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a function that searches for files:

```
var filesForSec = Directory.GetFiles(@"\..\..\Project/myProject/SomeFolder", 
                                     "*.js", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And problem that such a search method does not work on different computers.
Please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: We need more details. Any exception or error message?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Sorry for little info. I always must find the same folder, and it has to search for files. But the location of this folder varies among different computers.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: for example in my computer my project is on disk C/Program Files/...but on another computer it is on D/Games/..

Comment: But presumably the code that you've posted runs inside that folder, right? So it should be able to find out where it is, and then move back up the folder hierarchy. The problem however is that "..\..\..." is in relation to the current *working directory* which might be different from *the directory containing the currently executing code*.

Comment: @GeraySuinov So, how do you think `Directory.GetFiles` method can knows which directory in used current computer? First parameter need exactly full path.

Comment: and regardless of where the project I need to find it (the project) is always the same folders.

Comment: @Soner Gönül i show what i used, It doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
var filesForSec = Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.js",    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

or

```
var filesForSec = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.js", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each computer (I assume on the network) would be a separate root or a separate drive, you can't do it in one call to `Directory.GetFiles()`.

The same would apply to `C:` and `D:` drives. You have to search each one separately.

You've given very little other info.  You'll have to get a list of the computers or mapped drives to search, loop through them and get the files in the path you need for each one.

Comment: Sorry for little info. I always must find the same folder, and it has to search for files. But the location of this folder varies among different computers.

Comment: You need to either be TOLD where it was installed or be guaranteed that it's installed in the same RELATIVE location. There's no other options.